# Ошибка при неявном преобразовании

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stackoverflow

Пишу класс рациональных чисел. При неявном преобразовании возникает ошибка (StackOverflowException), причину которой понять не получается. Ниже код вызова, класса и скриншот ошибки

Вызов неявного преобразования

```
    [Test]
    public void ConvertFromInt()
    {
        Rational r = 5;
        AssertEqual(5, 1, r);
    }
```

Класс Rational

```
public class Rational
{
    public int Numerator { get; set; }
    public int Denominator
    {
        get { return Denominator; }
        set
        {
            if (value <= 0)
                IsNan = true;
            else
                IsNan = false;
            Denominator = value;
        }
    }
    public bool IsNan { get; set; }

    public Rational(int numenator, int detominator)
    {
        Numerator = numenator;
        Denominator = detominator;
    }
    public Rational(int numenator) : this(numenator,1) { }
    public static implicit operator Rational(int number)
    {
        return new Rational(number);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Внутри сеттера свойства `Denominator` опять вызывается он же - бесконечная рекурсия.

Comment: Предвосхищая будущий вопрос о неработающем сравнении: вам нужно реализовать в этом классе методы `GetHashCode` и `Equals`.

Comment: А почему отрицательный делитель это IsNan ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну либо это должна быть `struct`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В сеттере свойства Denominator вы присваиваетe value этому же свойству. Это вызывает бесконечную рекурсию и StackOverflowException. Вам следует завести закрытое (private) поле `denominator` и присаивать value ему

Comment: или писать `get; set { ваш код }` тогда свойство сформируется автоматически, без закрытых полей

Comment: @kleshenki если в сеттер нужно заложить логику, то без полей никак же

Comment: почему, есть ключевое слово value, которое представляет собой значение скрытого поля, сформированного для этого свойства. Оно даже используется в коде. Для уточнения, можно написать `get {return value;} set {код}`, но это совсем необязательно

Comment: @kleshenki напишите свой ответ, я не понимаю, что вы хотите дополнить.

Comment: `public int Denominator { get; set {if (value <= 0)
                IsNan = true;
            else
                IsNan = false;
            Denominator = value;}`

Comment: @kleshenki Это же код автора вопроса и с ним проблема

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, недоглядел.